# How can I observe my own actions via terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal

To understand Linux better I want to see which commands run in background. For example when I create new file via GUI, is there any way to see the which command runs in terminal?

Answer (score 2):

If you create something via a GUI, normally the only command that runs **is** the GUI, it doesn't call other commands that you would invoke from the commandline.

E.g. if the GUI is used to create a directory, it calls the C function `mkdir()`, not the command `mkdir` that you would use on the commandline (`mkdir` uses `mkdir()` as well and they both rely on a system call to actually create the directory on the filesystem).

You could try to run your GUI under `strace` to see what *system calls* it makes , but you have to make sure it stays in the foreground.

Comment: This isn't usually true.